# How to set up the oscillator frequencies of a STM32F103 with NuttX?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, nuttx

I'm completly new to this topic so please forgive my beginner mistakes :)

I'm on an internship where my task is to implement NuttX on a self created board from the company (with a STM32F103). To get started I followed the Youtube series "Getting started with NuttX" from the NuttX Channel step by step. But he is using a STM32F103-minimum board with a 8 MHz oscillator while the board of the company works with a 16 MHz oscillator.
I already changed some values in the "board.h" file so I can interact with the NuttShell via minicom but if I try the NuttX userleds example the led is blinking with double speed. I will post that changes tomorrow when I'm at work but if I remember corretly it was:

```
XTAL Frequency = 8 Mhz    --> 16 MHz
PLL Frequency  = 9*XTAL   --> 9*XTAL/2
PCLK2          = HCLK     --> 2*HCLK
PCLK           = HCLK/2   --> HCLK
```

I also used the NuttX PWM example to test the frequencies of the timers 1-4 and all of them worked correctly (input frequency matched output frequency).

I would appreciate any help to set up the frequencies correctly :)
Also methods to efficiently test the clocks and timers would help immensily.

Best regards
Miguel